# Change a blank space to a tilde using an if statement

Tags: java

This is in response to my many questions about resolving one of my programs. So right now, I'm trying to count the number of vowels in a text file that is inputted and then output it back to the text file. However, in this case, I also need to change any blank spaces in the text file to a tilde/tilda(~). If you take a look at the line after the massive if statement block, there is one if statement saying if the character is a blank space, then change it to a tilde.

I know strings are immutable, so thats why I'm not sure about how to change it. I don't really want a new string...but that might be my only option.

```
//Name: Allen Li
    //Program file: Vowels.Java 
    //Purpose: Using File IO, read a file's input and output this text to a new text file
    //When outputting, all blank spaces will be changed to tildes and there will be a count of each vowel(AEIOU)


    import java.util.Scanner; //input
    import java.io.File; //IO
    import java.io.IOException; //IO exception class
    import java.io.FileWriter; //file output
    import java.io.FileReader; //file input
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException; //if file isnt found, file not found class

    public class Vowels { //class
     public static void main(String[] args) { //main method

      try { //try block
       FileReader poetry = new FileReader("poetry.txt"); 
       FileWriter dentist = new FileWriter( 
         "LI_ALLEN_dentist.txt"); 

       int a; 
       while ((a = poetry.read()) != -1) { 
        dentist.write(a); 
        System.out.print((char) a); //print the file to the monitor
       } 

       poetry.close(); 
       dentist.close(); 

       Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File( 
         "LI_ALLEN_dentist.txt")); 

       int numOfVowelsA = 0; //count #s of A/E/I/O/U vowels
       int numOfVowelsE = 0; 
       int numOfVowelsI = 0; 
       int numOfVowelsO = 0; 
       int numOfVowelsU = 0; 

       while (inFile.hasNext()) { 

        String sentence = inFile.next(); 

        for (int i = 0; i <= sentence.length() - 1; i++) { 

          if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'a') { 
          numOfVowelsA++; 
         } 
         if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'e') { 
          numOfVowelsE++; 
         } 
         if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'i') { 
          numOfVowelsI++; 
         } 
         if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'o') { 
          numOfVowelsO++; 
         } 
         if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'u') { 
          numOfVowelsU++; 
          }
         if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == ' '){

                }
             } 

        System.out.println("The number of A vowels is: " + numOfVowelsA);
         System.out.println("The number of E vowels is: " + numOfVowelsE);
         System.out.println("The number of I vowels is: " + numOfVowelsI);
         System.out.println("The number of O vowels is: " + numOfVowelsO);
         System.out.println("The number of U vowels is: " + numOfVowelsU);

       }
          } catch (FileNotFoundException i) { 
            System.out.println("The file you are trying to use as input is not found. " + i); 
          } catch (IOException i) { 
            System.out.println("There is an issue with the input or output file. " + i); 
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Why not, when reading/writing the file, check to see if `a` == `' '` and change it there, `a = '~'` before writing it...?

Comment: I have to count the number of vowels and I thought as I go line by line why not just change the blank spaces to tildes since I had the opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

```
String modified_sentence = sentence.replaceAll(" ", "~");
```

and then continue with "modified_sentence"

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= modified_sentence.length() - 1; i++) { 

      if (modified_sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'a') { 
      numOfVowelsA++; 

      // continue
```

**EDIT**

to continue writing to the same file, you have to open it in the append mode like this

```
   FileWriter dentist = new FileWriter( 
     "LI_ALLEN_dentist.txt",true);  // notice the true at the end
```

Comment: Couldn't I just continue with sentence and when it reaches that step, just say sentence = sentence.replaceAll(" ", "~"); ?

Comment: Okay thanks. For that if statement I could just do: if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == ' '){
         sentence = sentence.replaceAll(" ", "~"); 
            }

Comment: Last thing - since I closed off the output to LI_ALLEN_dentist.txt is it possible to reopen and print my new modified text to the file? I need to do that. @AnkitRustagi

Comment: Yes. That should work. But the reason i had placed it at the top ahead of all if statements was because every sentence will have at-least a few empty spaces. So instead of checking for an empty space we can blindly go ahead and remove any empty space inside the sentence. Even if you dont have any empty space (unlikely) you would get the original string back. Thus saving the overhead of an if statement.

Comment: Oh okay so if I placed it before: int a; 
       while ((a = poetry.read()) != -1) { 
        dentist.write(a); 
        System.out.print((char) a); //print the file to the monitor
       }, I would actually have a file that removes the empty spaces before printing it back out to the file, correct? @AnkitRustagi

Comment: yes, but note that you were using inFile earlier. You could do the same thing with a bit of modifications there as well. About adding content to a file, you'll have to open it in append mode. This would not remove the old content add new content to the old content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40614/discussion-between-allenlistar-and-ankit-rustagi)

Answer (score 1):

> I know strings are immutable, so thats why I'm not sure about how to
>   change it. I don't really want a new string...but that might be my
>   only option.

Well, that does sound like your only option. Regardless of the approach you take, if you're given a fixed base string to work with, and you need to alter it somehow (via a regex, `StringBuilder`, `replaceAll`, w/e) you're going to end up with a new string.

I think the best approach here would be to use a `StringBuilder` though. especially if you're reading from a file.

Comment: Technically in our APCS class we haven't done StringBuilder at all and I do really want to use it since it's literally a string thats mutable. However, I don't want to particularly stand out my code so I'd like to keep StringBuilder as a last option only.